# Enable the MySQL Binary log

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

How do I enable the Binary log in mySQL. I have tried:

1) Entering this SQL code on phpmyadmin

```
SET GLOBAL log_bin ='ON'
```

This gave me an error message that bin_log is a read-only file;

2) Inserting this into my.ini file below [mysqld]

```
--log-bin= C:\mySqlbinlog
```

This displays that I cannot access the database when I try to get to the webpage.

Any idea how I can enable the Binary Log through phpmyadmin or in the my.ini file? Any help appreciated.

Comment: the `--` is only for options given when starting the mysql server from the command line. Use the version without the '--' in the `my.cgf'

Answer (score 3):

Just Put **log_bin** parameter after mysqld. Please give path for binlog where you have large amount of space because binlog eats lots of disk space.

```
log_bin = "path where want to store bin files.extension"
```

You can also use some other parameters like **max_binlog_size**, **max_binlog_cache_size**, 
**sync_binlog** for well performance

For More Here's [a link] (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-options-binary-log.html)

Comment: The format for the command line option to mysqld is `--log-bin`, not `log_bin`. Also, "If you supply an extension in the log name (for example, --log-bin=base_name.extension), the extension is silently removed and ignored." - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/binary-log.html

Comment: `log_bin` is a variable name for 'my.ini' file variable should be put after [mysqld] section. `--log-bin` is parameter for commandline-format. That's why i have preferred log_bin. About extension you are right, thanks for that.

Comment: where do I put the command line in my my.ini file. No matter what I try I keep getting the error that the page cannot connect to the server I have tried right after the [mysqld] line, after the server port connection, before the innodb section and right at the end of the document

Comment: I have done it! it needed 'server-id=1 log-bin=mysqlbin sync_binlog=1'

Comment: I now cannot view the file binlog000001. Any ideas how I entered this into phpmyadmin shell> mysqlbinlog binlog.000001

Comment: TO VIEW BINLOG FILE IN readable FORMAT USE mysqlbinlog utility we can VIEW the BINLOG FILE content. 
IF it's a single file you can recover using: 
mysqlbinlog /var/lib/mysql-bin.000016 | mysql –uroot –pRe12 

If it's multiple files THEN just EXTRACT ALL content TO ONE .SQL FILE AND directly RESTORE it: 
mysqlbinlog -v /var/lib/mysql-bin.000016 > /LOGS/allbinlog.sql 

Try this below FOR more musqlbinlog UTILITY OPTIONS: 
mysqlbinlog --help

Comment: @KClark I suggest you create a new question if you've solved your first problem and now have a separate one. It will help others who search for your new problem in future, and keeps the site cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#option_mysqld_log-bin), the option-file format is `log-bin`, so you should put this in your my.ini (under the `[mysqld]` heading):

```
log-bin=C:\mySqlbinlog
```

Don't forget to restart the MySQL server process afterward!

Comment: In my case log-bin was commented with #. Don't forget to uncomment it if that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

I currently use wamp with MySQL ver 5.6.17 so your milage may vary.

Open your my.ini file and scroll through it. You're looking for the `[mysqld]` section. Add `log-bin=C:\Your_Dir_Here` to the `[mysqld]` section. Restart the MySQL services. Once the restart has finished, login to MySQL. Run the command `SHOW BINARY LOGS;`

You should then see an output like this:

```
+------------------+-----------+
| Log_name         | File_size |
+------------------+-----------+
| MySQL_Log.000001 |       120 |
+------------------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**NOTE**
I don't know exactly how `log-bin` works but I would recommend an absolute path so you know exactly where your log files will be. Also, your MySQL installation won't read the `my.ini` file until it's services restart.

**Further reading**
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/binary-log.html

This link covers a great deal about the binary logs. It literally covers too much for me to even gloss over.

If I've left something out or if I was vague on something, leave a comment and I'll try to reply back.